# CSS Problem in IE7

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-7

I am using asp:button for my asp.net project.
I wrote one css Class.  It perfectly apply Css style and show image in the asp:button.
It is working fine in FF, Safari and IE8.
But the Css Class does not work in IE7, How to solve? and my Code is:

```
.likeImage {
    background-image:url('images/LikeNew.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
    width:65px;
    height:24px;
    cursor:default;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: two padding is there padding-left:5px and padding:0px; remove padding:0px or give only padding:0 0 0 5px;. i hope this will not create a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You used `(padding-left:5px;)` and `(padding:0)` this is not the right way.
just use

```
padding:5px;
```

Then please check.

Comment: padding-left: 5px is not the same as yours padding: 5px, it should be padding: 0 0 0 5px

Answer (score 1):

Add `border:0;` in your CSS for `asp:button`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tips.  I added the border 0 for asp:button.  Its working perfectly for me in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
padding: 0 0 0 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer calculates padding towards inside of a block, while other browsers calculates padding towards outside of a block.

In IE, `Actual Width` = `CSS width`.

Others, `Actual Width` = `CSS width` + `Left Padding` + `Right Padding`.

The second one is standard CSS approved by W3C.